# how to open live website on same computer if virtual host has same name

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I just setup a virtual host (on localhost using wamp) with name example123.com and i have same domain name example123.com with live website on it.

This is what was created on httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example123.com
    DocumentRoot "e:/wamp/www/example123"
    <Directory  "e:/wamp/www/example123/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this on C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1   example123.com
::1 example123.com
```

Now, when i go on example123.com on browser it always open my localhost folder, but not the actual website. when i stop wamp server it shows error.

How do i open the live website?

Anyones help will be appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your website's root directory lacks `index.html` or similar index page and you have `+Index` on. Thus apache will show the content in your directory. BTW, you should disable `MultiView` (By replacing + with -) since it has severe security problem.

Comment: Thank you for info. Both root directory have index.php page (localhost as well as online host).

Comment: @Mustafa Well, you have to tell apache to treat your index.php as index page since apache itself is a just web server that does not know php and other things. Add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to let apache recognize it.